# Changing the default display of line breaks in search window?

Tags: bbedit

I recently switched from Textwrangler to BBEdit. I use these editors to perform large multi-file GREP-search mainly. But in BBEdit I noticed that line breaks automatically get converted to `\n` in the search window, and that makes in very hard for me to get an overview of the search I'm about to perform, when everything is on one line.

When I copy a text with line breaks, for example

```
Line

Line

Line
```

and paste it in the search window, it looks like this:

`Line\n\nLine\n\nLine`

In TextWrangler I was able to see the line breaks as line breaks, not `\n`. How can I change that in BBEdit?

Thanks!